# Session Destroyed After copy (CTRL+C) text from UI to Excel/Word

Tags: java, spring, session, copy-paste, webdav

This is happening in a web application based on Spring boot + Angular JS. We are also using WebDAV to upload/read documents from alfresco. 
For example, when a user clicks a link in UI, it will download document from alfresco and opens word/excel to show it.

**Scenario:** The user is copying text from the application UI using CTRL+C and pasting into excel/word. In this case, excel/word is **NOT** opened via web application, but **clicking shortcut menu from Windows Desktop**.

**What is happening:** When the user does this for the 1st time, excel/word shows **login popup**, once he logs into it (using web application's credentials), **web application's session destroyed**.

**Question:**
How Excel/Word which was opened **outside** of application knows about **application's Session** and opens login popup while pasting text?

Comment: Why would excel/word show a login popup?

Comment: No need to, but it happens. Why is the actual question